# Ui-router to systems with many modules

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a problem, a Controller called OrderController standing on two modules, Sales and Supply. When I make the route that will use this controller as I can define which of the two controllers I want to use, how can I define which controller's module? I tried to register the route separately in each module, but still not the right.

Full code: https://plnkr.co/edit/iLUuUNKWZJhg23rrk1zB?p=preview

acmeModule.js

```
var app = 
    angular
    .module('acme', [

        // Angular UI
        'ui.router',

        // Acme modules
        'acme.sales',
        'acme.supply',
    ]);

app.config(config);

config.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");

    $stateProvider
        .state("home", {
            url: "/home",
            template: "Home"
        })
}
```

salesModule.js

```
var app = 
    angular
    .module('acme.sales', ['ui.router']);

app.config(config);

config.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state("orderBySales", {
            url: "/orderBySales",
            templateUrl: "content.html",
            controller: 'OrderController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        });
}

app.controller('OrderController', OrderController);

function OrderController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.Content = "Order by Sales";
}
```

supplyModule.js

```
var app = 
    angular
    .module('acme.supply', ['ui.router']);

app.config(config);

config.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state("orderBySupply", {
            url: "/orderBySupply",
            templateUrl: "content.html",
            controller: 'OrderController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        });
}

app.controller('OrderController', OrderController);

function OrderController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.Content = "Order by Supply";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to name the controller differently, otherwise one controller overwrites the other one. In this constellation (plunker) it is the controller of module acme.supply.

Call it `SupplyOrderController` and `SalesOrderController`.